# Is there a low-cost alternate to AWS Open Search

Tags: amazon-web-services

We want to implement a full-text search in AWS and we know DynamoDB is not suitable for that. AWS Open Search is very expensive for small projects. Is there a low-cost alternative in the AWS environment? Lambda with cache or?

Comment: Running your own copy of something is usually much cheaper than the AWS service. Have you considered running your own ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a low-cost alternative to AWS OpenSearch, there are several options you can consider.

One option is to use a third-party service like [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/). I've used Algolia for my project, [awsnews.info](https://awsnews.info/), and found it to be a good alternative. It's not Elasticsearch, but it does provide search functionality and has a free tier for up to 10K records. For Open Source projects they offer a free tier up to 100k records. For higher volumes they have pay-as-you-go pricing so you pay a small fee for going over a free tier.

Another option is to consider other Elasticsearch hosting services that offer more flexible pricing. Services like Bonsai or Searchly could be a good fit for your needs. You can check out Searchly's pricing [here](http://www.searchly.com/pricing).

If you're open to more experimental solutions, there are a couple of proof-of-concept options that use AWS services under the hood. One is [Lambda Serverless Search](https://github.com/rlingineni/Lambda-Serverless-Search), which uses S3. Another is a solution which uses Lambda and EFS for full-text search on DynamoDB. You can read more about it [here](https://jakejscott.com/full-text-search-for-dynamodb-using-lambda-efs-tantivy-and-rust).

Please note that these last two options are not widely used in production and you would need to maintain these solutions yourself.

Lastly, AWS OpenSearch does offer a serverless option. However, it doesn't scale to 0 and can still be quite expensive, so it might not be the best fit for small projects.